# openJPA IN parameter type as collection

Tags: jpa, openjpa

Can I give `List<Long>` as the `IN` parameter when using openJPA?

The database I am using is MySQL latest version. The example query which I am trying to work is as below and also pasted the error which I am getting. Please let me know what I need to do to get this working.

```sql
Select * from table t where c in (?)
```

```java
.createNativeQuery(TOPIC)
.setParameter(1, listNo)
```

Where `listNo` is `List<Long>`.

#### Error

> 19:46:47,376 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component TopicService for method public abstract com.zreflect.emyed.vo.circle.TopicVO[] com.zreflect.emyed.ejb.interfaces.ITopicService.getSelectedTopics(long,java.util.List,com.zreflect.emyed.vo.UserSession): javax.ejb.EJBException: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The specified parameter of type "class java.util.ArrayList" is not a valid query parameter.

Comment: Why "native" query? JPQL allows an IN query taking a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the array to string seperated by comma and passed the parameter value.

It is working this way now as array are not supported for native query.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify if the snippet is JPQL or raw SQL.
There is also two more ways of build a query:
NamedQueries
or
CriteriaBuilder.
potentially even more.

I think the easiest way would be using a JPQL query.

```
String JPQL = "Select * from table t where c in (:value)"

ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(1);
```

You can use the method:

```
TypedQuery.setParameter("value",myList);
```

See: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

But: The list does always need to have at least one item. I think empty lists will not work, or produce a wrong SQL statement.

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

How about ParameterExpression? How do you construct an 'in' expression using ParameterExpression and TypedQuery.setParameter?